# How do you create a Stream in Dart?

Tags: dart

I basically know how to use them; for instance listening to the onClick Stream of an Element.

But, how do you set up your own Streams?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Simple example

Here's a complete working example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class Application {
  Stream onExit;
  
  Application() {
    // Create a stream controller and assign its stream to "onExit".
    var controller = new StreamController();
    onExit = controller.stream;

    // Create some class that uses our stream.
    new UserOfStream(this);
    
    // Whenever we exit the application, notify everyone about it first.
    controller.add('we are shutting down!');
    exit(0);
  }
}

class UserOfStream {
  UserOfStream(app) {
    app.onExit.listen((String message) => print(message));
  }
}

main() => new Application();
```

You can also do cool things like check if there are subscribers with `controller.hasListener` or you can [signal an error](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamController.html#addError). Be sure to check the API documentation on [`StreamController`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamController.html).

You can use `new StreamController.broadcast()` for allowing multiple listeners.

### For copy-pasters

Here's a simple way to create a stream (great snippet for copy-pasters):

```dart
class Something {
  StreamController _onExitController = new StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get onExit => _onExitController.stream;
}
```

Then the class can just access `_onExitController` to control the stream (to for example `.add()`).

Comment: The StreamController recently switched its default behavior to only accept a single listener.
If you want to allow more than one listener, change the "new StreamController" to "new StreamController.broadcast". (This is for bleeding edge. Trunk currently still calls it "StreamController.multiSubscription").

Comment: There are some significant differences between single-subscription and broadcast streams that stream users should be aware of. See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/broadcast-streams/.

Comment: Note that `Stream` and `StreamController` are generics. `StreamController<String>` provides a `Stream<String>` for instance.

Comment: I'm getting: `Close instances of dart.core.sink`

Comment: I'm not sure why, but adding `.broadcast()` to the stream controller instantiation caused my `StreamBuilder` `snapshot.hasData` to always be false even after I have added data with `StreamController.add`. Removing `.broadcast()` fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to `StreamController` you can instantiate a `Stream` directly with one of its named constructors:

- `Stream.fromFuture()` Returns a stream that fires one event (whatever the `Future` completes to.)
- `Stream.fromIterable()` Returns a stream that converts the `Iterable` elements to a sequence of events.
- `Stream.periodic()` Returns a stream that fires a computed event periodically.

This is very handy as you can write code that expects to consume a stream, but you have multiple choices as to how to feed events to that class. For example: `Stream.fromIterable()`  could be used in a unit test to fire a known sequence of events to a class that otherwise normally would be fed data events read from a file.

Answer (score 2):

I just created a new Dart library called [event_stream](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/event_stream) to make creating custom events on your classes easier.  Here is an example:

```csharp
class ClassWithEvents implements NotifyPropertyChanged {
  String _someProperty;

  final EventStream<PropertyChangedEventArgs> _onPropertyChangedEvent = new EventStream<PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
  Stream<PropertyChangedEventArgs> get onPropertyChanged => _onPropertyChangedEvent.stream;

  final EventStream _onClosedEvent = new EventStream();
  Stream get onClosed => _onClosedEvent.stream;

  String get someProperty => _someProperty;
  set someProperty(String value) {
    _onPropertyChangedEvent.signal(new PropertyChangedEventArgs('someProperty', value));
    _someProperty = value;
  }

  close() {
    _onClosedEvent.signal();
  }
}

main() {
  var c = new ClassWithEvents();
  c.onPropertyChanged.listen((PropertyChangedEventArgs<String> args) => print('changed: name=${args.propertyName} value=${args.value}'));
  c.onClosed.listen((_) => print('closed'));
  c.someProperty = "test";
  c.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is sample with from flutter bloc

1. Add dependency

   rxdart: ^0.27.2
2. Create stream controller

final _todoStreamController = BehaviorSubject<List>.seeded(const []);

3. Update when there is a change

Future saveTodo(Todo todo) {
final todos = [..._todoStreamController.value];
final todoIndex = todos.indexWhere((t) => t.id == todo.id);
if (todoIndex >= 0) {
todos[todoIndex] = todo;
} else {
todos.add(todo);
}

```
_todoStreamController.add(todos);
```

}

4. Broadcast

   Stream<List> getTodos() => _todoStreamController.asBroadcastStream();
5. Subscribe

Future _onSubscriptionRequested(
TodosOverviewSubscriptionRequested event,
Emitter emit,
) async {
emit(state.copyWith(status: () => TodosOverviewStatus.loading));

```
await emit.forEach<List<Todo>>(
  _todosRepository.getTodos(),
  onData: (todos) => state.copyWith(
    status: () => TodosOverviewStatus.success,
    todos: () => todos,
  ),
  onError: (_, __) => state.copyWith(
    status: () => TodosOverviewStatus.failure,
  ),
);
```

}

[REF LINK](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial?id=localstoragetodosapi)