# Getting multiple references to the same method = multiple objects?

Tags: dart

I'm new to Dart, so maybe I'm missing something here:

**This works:**

In my `main()`, I have this:

```as3
var a = _someFunction;
var b = _someFunction;
print("${a == b}"); // true. correct!
```

Where `_someFunction` is another top-level function.

**This does NOT work:** (at least not how I'm expecting it to)

Given this class...

```as3
class Dummy {

    void start() {
        var a = _onEvent;
        var b = _onEvent;
        print(a == b); // false. ???????
    }

    void _onEvent() {
    }
}
```

Instantiating it from `main()` and calling its `start()` method results in `false`. Apparently a new instance of some function or closure object is created and returned whenever my code obtains a reference to `_onEvent`.

**Is this intentional behaviour?**

I would expect that obtaining multiple references to the same method of the same instance returns the same object each time. Perhaps this is intended for some reason. If so; what reason? Or is this a bug/oversight/limitation of VM perhaps?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Could you please share the use case that prompted you to look into this behavior? Given what you were trying to do, there may be some decent workarounds available to you.

Comment: I was adding method references as event handlers and attempting to remove them again (from a `List`, which failed due to the instances being different each time). I read about some workarounds and in the end opted to store the method reference in a "subscription" object at the time of adding the event handler, much like Dart's own `StreamSubscription` works, I imagine. But yeah, I dislike the behaviour...

Comment: Thanks for the background. Here is an example of making your own stream, which might help model your events, subscriptions, etc using the built-in classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536437/how-do-you-create-a-stream-in-dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the behaviour seems to be intentional, but the following defect is open since May 2012:  https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=144

Comment: Just to clarify, this issue is closed as of now. If you have a compelling use case that requires this functionality, please do add it to the issue. I personally find this behavior non-obvious, but I don't know if it will be revisited.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to guess, I'd say that setting "var a = _onEvent;" creates a bound method, which is some sort of object that contains both the function as well as this. You are asking for bound methods to be canonicalized. However, that would require the team to create a map of them, which could lead to worries about memory leaks.

I think they made "var a = _someFunction;" work early on because they needed static functions to be constants so that they could be assigned to consts. This was so that they could write things like:

const logger = someStaticLoggingFunction;

This was in the days before statics were lazily evaluated.

In any case, I would say that comparing closures for equality is a edge case for most languages. Take all of the above with a grain of salt. It's just my best guess based on my knowledge of the system. As far as I can tell, the language spec doesn't say anything about this.

Actually, now that I've read (https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=144), the discussion is actually pretty good. What I wrote above roughly matches it.