# Dart equivalent of Input and Output Stream from Java

Tags: java, dart

What is the equivalent of *Java's `InputStream` and `OutputStream`* in Dart?

Comment: In which use case?

Comment: ex: looking for a similar code in DART as like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/sample-code-illustrating-secure-socket-connection-client-and-server.htm#JSSEC-GUID-AA1C27A1-2CA8-4309-B281-D6199F60E666

Comment: SSL/TLS sockets are created with [SecureServerSocket](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/SecureServerSocket-class.html). Here is a [good article](http://jamesslocum.com/post/70003236123) demonstrating their use (it's pretty old and meant for Dart 1 but should still be fine).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your usecase.

Maybe take a look at

- Dart´s `File` class:
  https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/File-class.html
- Dart´s `Socket`class: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/Socket-class.html

https://dart-lang.github.io/server/tls-ssl.html could also be interesting for you, if understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Stream and Sink orStreamSink

- [Using Stream/Sink in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995237/using-stream-sink-in-flutter)
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/StreamSink-class.html